# Apache beam Kafka [ No TransformEvaluator registered for UNBOUNDED transform Read(KafkaUnboundedSource)]

Tags: apache-beam

I am using simple Kafka reader and country key , while running on spark I am getting following error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No TransformEvaluator registered for UNBOUNDED transform Read(KafkaUnboundedSource)
>       at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:588)
>       at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.streaming.StreamingTransformTranslator$Translator.translateUnbounded(StreamingTransformTranslator.java:560)
>       at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkRunner$Evaluator.translate(SparkRunner.java:451)

I am not able to get anything about this error

```
 pipeline
                        .apply(
                                KafkaIO.<String, String>read()
                                        .withBootstrapServers(options.getBootstrap())
                                        .withTopic(options.getInputTopic())
                                        .withKeyDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
                                        .withValueDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
                                        .withConsumerConfigUpdates(ImmutableMap.of("group.id", (Object) "test1"))
                                        .withoutMetadata())


                        .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<String, String>, MetricData>() {....
```

Comment: Did you use a "fat" jar while running it on Spark?

Comment: yes through maven-assembly-plugin

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same exception and for me (note: I use Apache Beam and sbt), adding the following assembly merge strategy solved the issue:

```scala
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly ~= { old =>
    {
      case s if s.endsWith(".properties")           => MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
      case s if s.endsWith("pom.xml")               => MergeStrategy.last
      case s if s.endsWith(".class")                => MergeStrategy.last
      case s if s.endsWith(".proto")                => MergeStrategy.last
      case s if s.endsWith("libjansi.jnilib")       => MergeStrategy.last
      case s if s.endsWith("jansi.dll")             => MergeStrategy.rename
      case s if s.endsWith("libjansi.so")           => MergeStrategy.rename
      case s if s.endsWith("libsnappyjava.jnilib")  => MergeStrategy.last
      case s if s.endsWith("libsnappyjava.so")      => MergeStrategy.last
      case s if s.endsWith("snappyjava_snappy.dll") => MergeStrategy.last
      case s if s.endsWith(".dtd")                  => MergeStrategy.rename
      case s if s.endsWith(".xsd")                  => MergeStrategy.rename
      case PathList("META-INF", "services", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem") =>
        MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
      case s => old(s)
    }
```

So you might want to have a look at the "shading" part in the official [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/spark/) and add the following to you `pom.xml` file (I guess it is not there, yet. Please excuse if I am wrong.):

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
    <filters>
      <filter>
        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
          <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
          <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </filter>
    </filters>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
        <shadedClassifierName>shaded</shadedClassifierName>
        <transformers>
          <transformer
            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
        </transformers>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: yes its was problem with shade only I forget to update here